# Add attribute to a file/folder

Tags: windows, powershell, compression, file-attributes, recursive

I tried that to add an attribute to a file/folder

```
Get-ChildItem '$PATH' -Recurse | foreach{$_.Attributes = $_.Attributes + 'Compressed'}
```

Problem is that it create a cycle like that : `Not compressed` > `Compressed` > `Compressed, Offline` > `Compressed, NotContentIndexed` > `Compressed, Offline, NotContentIndexed`

So the command should work fine on any element on $PATH that aren't compressed at all, but if there is the attribute, it will add/delete `Offline, NotContentIndexed` to the attributes (`Compressed` and any other irrelevant attributes stays fine), considering that I never asked for that. I only want to add/let `Compressed` without touching anything else

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Last line of the post states "I only want to add/let `Compressed` without touching anything else"

Comment: from what i can tell you need to give it an ARRAY of the items, not a string.

Comment: I don’t fully understand what’s happening — is the sequence you show really what you’re getting? — and I don’t know PowerShell. But it looks like `Attributes` is a bitmap, and you don’t want to do ordinary arithmetic on a bitmap; you need a logical operation. Can you do `$_.Attributes = $_.Attributes | 'Compressed'`?

Comment: You can test if a file or folder is compressed or not using something like `(Get-Item -Path 'X:\theFileOrFolder').Attributes -band 'Compressed'` If that returns 'Compressed', then... it is compressed otherwise it is not. Is that what you mean?  (`-band` stands for Binary AND and in this case it test for the bitmap including the value 2048 or not. 'Compressed' is easier to write than the numeric value and PowerShell will understand that)